# MAMP 2.0.1 with Ruby on Rails 3.2.0 on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, mamp

This has been asked before, but I couldn't find a newer result than 2010. A lot can change in two years. The fact that it hasn't been asked since, makes me think, that maybe I'm missing something.

So. Is there an easy way, to setup Ruby On Rails 3.2.0 to work With MAMP PRO on Mac OS X Lion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for work with PHP with MAMP 2.0.5  and RAILS  with two databases different for each. PHP uses mysql from MAMP and RAILS a other database installed via Homebrew.

I use mac os lion 10.7.3

I explain how I did

1-The first step is delete all. Delete MAMP, MAMP PRO, the folders in applications (be carefully with your projects if they are in the MAMP folder) and all the mysql servers that you have installed. (visit this link for how remove mysql from mac osx lion http://johnmcostaiii.net/2011/removing-mysql-osx-lion/)

2-Install the lattest version of Xcode (via App Store)

3-Install homebrew (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation)

4-Install rvm and ruby 1.9.3. Follow the steps of quick start guide (http://beginrescueend.com/)

5-Open a terminal and install mysql via homebrew

```
brew install mysql
```

Read the installations of mysql notes (on terminal) and follow the steps. (create alias, password, start and initialize database, etc)

6- Say at rvm that uses the ruby version 1.9.3

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

7- If you want, you can create a gemsets (explained at rvm webpage) and use it

```
rvm gemset create "gemset_name"

use 1.9.3@gemset_name
```

8- Install rails

```
gem install rails
```

9 - Create a app with mysql gems

```
rails new name_app -d mysql
```

And it works!

10 - Install MAMP PRO 2.0.5

11 - Test with any PHP page with database

And it works!

(After install and run MAMP, I created a vhosts for try if all work fine, but the vhosts don´t work properly. I spent 1 hour searching a solution, but the solution for me was restart the computer finally ... and ... )

I hope that help you! I lost many hours looking for the solution

(I followed this steps with changes: http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/)

**edit:** everytime you open the console and work with rails you must type in the console

```
rvm use 1.9.3@gemset_name
```

or create a file with this command and save in the folder of your rails app with name

```
.rvmrc
```

Comment: Thanks, I already found a solution for myself and blogged about it, just forgot that I asked :)
http://www.themer.me/blog/tutorials/ruby-on-rails-and-mamp-pro

Comment: If you add the --default switch to rvm (rvm use 1.9.3 --default) you don't need to enter this every time you use rails in the terminal. Probably the same if you're using your gemset too?