# Installing Ruby on Rails on Mac OS X 10.7.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on my Mac Machine. I have Xcode installed as well as the terminal command tools.

This is the output after running **$ bundle install**
I'm also tried sudo **$ sudo bundle install** and have gotten the same results.

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using Ascii85 (1.0.1) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.2.6) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.6) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.6) 
Using mime-types (1.18) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.6) 
Using active_reload (0.6.1) 
Using active_utils (1.0.3) 
Using json (1.7.3) 
Using money (3.7.1) 
Using activemerchant (1.21.0) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.6) 
Using activeresource (3.2.6) 
Using acts_as_list-rails3 (0.0.4) 
Using addressable (2.2.8) 
Using celerity (0.9.2) 
Using culerity (0.2.15) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.2) 
Using ffi (1.0.11) 
Using childprocess (0.3.1) 
Using libwebsocket (0.1.3) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.7) 
Using selenium-webdriver (2.21.0) 
Using xpath (0.1.4) 
Using capybara (0.4.1.2) 
Using jruby-jars (1.6.7) 
Using akephalos (0.2.5) 
Using ancestry (1.2.5) 
Using awesome_print (1.0.2) 
Using multi_xml (0.4.2) 
Using httparty (0.8.2) 
Using uuidtools (2.1.2) 
Using aws-sdk (1.4.0) 
Using breadcrumbs_on_rails (2.2.0) 
Using bundler (1.1.5) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.15.4) 
Using railties (3.2.6) 
Using rails (3.2.6) 
Using cache-machine (0.2.1) 
Using redis (2.2.2) 
Using cache-machine-redis (0.0.1) 
Using highline (1.6.13) 
Using net-ssh (2.5.2) 
Using net-scp (1.0.4) 
Using net-sftp (2.0.5) 
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0) 
Using capistrano (2.12.0) 
Using capistrano-ext (1.2.1) 
Using carrierwave (0.6.2) 
Using chronic (0.6.7) 
Using closure-compiler (1.1.6) 
Using cloudfiles (1.5.0.1) 
Using cocaine (0.2.1) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using columnize (0.3.6) 
Using configuration (1.3.1) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using gherkin (2.9.3) 
Using term-ansicolor (1.0.7) 
Using cucumber (1.1.9) 
Using daemons (1.1.8) 
Using dalli (2.0.3) 
Using database_cleaner (0.7.2) 
Using debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.3) 
Installing debugger-linecache (1.1.2) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- debugger/ruby_core_source (LoadError)
    from extconf.rb:2


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing debugger-linecache (1.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Unless you're having a permission issue, never use sudo on OS X. RVM doesn't require it and neither does homebrew. It will just cause you headaches down the road because you may end up installing something with root privileges that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

Visit this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9400424/1171049

I wrote a guide to install RubyOnRails through homebrew. Is a good way to install RubyonRails

i hope that this guide would be useful for you

> 2-Install the lattest version of Xcode (via App Store)
>
> 3-Install homebrew (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation)
>
> 4-Install rvm and ruby 1.9.3. Follow the steps of quick start guide (http://beginrescueend.com/)
>
> 5-Open a terminal and install mysql via homebrew

```
    brew install mysql
```

> Read the installations of mysql notes (on terminal) and follow the steps. (create alias, password, start and initialize database, etc)
>
> 6- Say at rvm that uses the ruby version 1.9.3

```
    rvm use 1.9.3
```

> 7- If you want, you can create a gemsets (explained at rvm webpage) and use it

```
    rvm gemset create "gemset_name"

    use 1.9.3@gemset_name
```

> 8- Install rails

```
    gem install rails
```

> 9 - Create a app with mysql gems

```
    rails new name_app -d mysql
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the version of Railsinstaller for mac at http://railsinstaller.org/